# How can textual "logic" be represented in a data structure

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, lexical-analysis

Given the string

```
{A} AND ({B} OR {C} OR ({D} AND {E}))
```

How can this be represented in a data structure?

Answer (score 1):

The "natural" representation is a tree. Each non-leaf node is an operator and its children are the operands. In your example, you'd have a root node labeled "AND" with two children. The left child is {A} and the right one is labeled "OR". This "OR" has three children, one labeled {B}, one labeled {C} and one labeled "AND". This last "AND" has two children, {D} and {E}.

If you wish "OR" to be a binary operator (rather than ternary or n-ary), you can have the "OR" with two children: one is {B} and the other is another "OR" whose children are {C} and the "AND".

Answer (score 1):

It's a circuit. If I were to wire up that equation on a breadboard with some transistors and LED's I'd draw the following schematic:

```
                 A
                /
output-----[AND]      B
                \    /
                 [OR]--C
                     \       D
                      \     /
                       [AND]
                            \
                             E
```

Coincidentally, this can even be structured as a simple map of arrays of maps. Let's use JSON as an example format for this data:

```
{AND:[
    A,
    {OR:[
        B,
        C,
        {AND:[
            D,
            E
        ]}
     ]}
]}
```

This is basically a graph. In the simplest case like in this example it is a tree but be warned: that is only an artefact of this example. In general it is a graph because you can have cycles in the structure (one element appearing in more than one place).

Here's an example of an equation that is not a neat tree:

```
{A} OR ({B} AND (NOT {A}))
```

This translates to:

```
               A-------------.
              /              |
output----[OR]       [NOT]<--'
              \     /
               [AND]
                    \
                     B
```